# libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found error

Tags: linux, swift, debian, libstdc++

I am trying to run swift 3.0 on debian 8(Jessie). However, I don't think there is the required version of libstdc++.so.6 file on my laptop. I typed "locate libstdc++.so.6" in the terminal. Below are the responses I get back in the terminal.

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20-gdb.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.20-gdb.py
```

I also typed "whereis GLIBCXX_3.4.21" in the terminal, and get

```
GLIBCXX_3.4:
```

I have also tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Besides that, I also tried

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Is there any other way to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I asked this question myself. I just downloaded the snapshot from Apple's official website. The thing was that I was following a tutorial which tied to download the snapshot for ubuntu via wget, but I got the snapshot for ubuntu 15 instead of the one for ubuntu 14. My guess is that ubuntu 15 is newer and therefore it has a newer version of the thing I asked....